# Do I have to create NSOperation subclass for each web service?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I always fetch data from web services using `GCD`. Now I have to use `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue`. But I am confused with the working of `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue`.

Suppose I have two APIs, Login API and Registration API. Do I have to create two `NSOperation` subclasses for it, like LoginOperation and RegistrationOperation? Or I could send various request in one `NSOperation` `Class`?

And how should I keep `NSOperationQueue` class central so that I keep adding operation class objects to it.

Please provide link for this type of sample project.

Comment: I highly recommend using AFNetworking for this

Comment: I have to create my own so that I can understand it in deep.

Comment: The networking operation model had a huge change in iOS7, you can use the old NSURLConnection model or the new NSURLSession. IF you want to understand the inner mechanism of wrapping something into an NSOperation you should start with easier operation than NSURLconnection where there are delegates callback involved. AFNetworking is also a really awesome point to start learning how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This will vary from project to project but generally you may want to have only one base subclass of `NSOperation` and subclass that for your specific requests such as `LoginOperation` or `RegistrationOperation`. You may want to look into `AFNetworking` since that is already a very well established networking library that subclasses `NSOperation`.

Depending on what you app is doing and how you want to manage your requests you may need more that one `NSOperationQueue`. This will help you keep track of the various requests and know if they have completed if needed, need to be syncronized, etc.

Have a look at this for something more in depth:
http://www.objc.io/issue-2/concurrency-apis-and-pitfalls.html